# Type Error when deploying to vercel but not when running `npm run build` Next 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a pretty simple next js 13.4 app using typescript. I am trying to deploy it to vercel and am getting constant type errors on the build in vercel. It appears that all the errors are related to 3rd party library types that are exported from d.ts files. The errors look like this:

```
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'legendOffsetX' does not exist in type 'CartesianMarkerProps<DatumValue>'.
  259 |               {
  260 |                 axis: 'y',
> 261 |                 legendOffsetX: 14,
      |                 ^
  262 |                 legendOffsetY: -8,
  263 |                 value:
  264 |                   forecastData && forecast / dailyFactor,
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

'CartesianMarkerProps' is an exported type from a d.ts file in a library I am using. However, if you open the type, the value it's calling out is present and correctly used.

```
export interface CartesianMarkerProps<V extends DatumValue = DatumValue> {
    axis: 'x' | 'y'
    value: V
    legend?: string
    legendOrientation?: 'horizontal' | 'vertical'
    legendPosition?: BoxAlign
    lineStyle?: Partial<React.CSSProperties>
    textStyle?: Partial<React.CSSProperties>
    legendOffsetX: number
    legendOffsetY: number
}
```

Then if I `//@ts-ignore` more issues will come up on other libraries.

The weird part is there are no TS errors in the code or when I run `npm run build`

I only started using TS recently so I don't know a ton about the tsconfig but here is mine currently:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Thanks for any help provided.